# Where are java classes stored in Oracle?

Tags: java, oracle, oracleinternals

Where is the java bytecode for loaded java classes stored within an oracle database? Specifically, is there a view or table I can use to obtain the raw bytes for java class schema objects within Oracle?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have used CREATE JAVA SOURCE command to load the Java Source into the Oracle database then you can go to the data dictionary view USER_SOURCE and find your Java Source.

If you need to display it or something, you can check out DBMS_JAVA.EXPORT_SOURCE which puts the source code in PL/SQL structures that you can manipulate.

Generally, if you want to just list all Java related stored objects you can execute the following:

```
SELECT
  object_name, 
  object_type, 
  status, 
  timestamp
FROM 
  user_objects
WHERE 
  (object_name NOT LIKE 'SYS_%' AND 
   object_name NOT LIKE 'CREATE$%' AND 
   object_name NOT LIKE 'JAVA$%' AND 
   object_name NOT LIKE 'LOADLOB%') AND
  object_type LIKE 'JAVA %'
ORDER BY
  object_type, 
  object_name;
```

Answer (score 3):

Java bytecode stored in `IDL_UB1$` table:

```
select o.NAME, i.PIECE 
from obj$ o, IDL_UB1$ i 
where o.type# = 29 
    and o.obj# = i.obj#
```